# I’m trying to save data on the database but it is saving each input change

Tags: reactjs, moralis

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import { NoMoralisContextProviderError } from 'react-moralis';

import './css/createpost.css'

import { useMoralis } from "react-moralis";

function CreatePost() {

    const [title, setTitle] = useState("")

    const [content, setContent] = useState("")

    const { Moralis, isInitialized } = useMoralis();

    const createNewPost = (e, title, content) => {

        e.preventDefault()

        const newPost = Moralis.Object.extend("Posts");

        const post = new newPost();

        post.set("title", title);

        post.set("content", content);

        post.save();

        return post;

    }

    return (

        <div>

            <div>

            <form action="#" className="createpost">

               <div class="data">

                  <label>Title</label>

                  <input type="text" required onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}/>

               </div>

               <div class="data">

                  <label>Content</label>

                  <input type="text" required onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}/>

               </div>

               <div class="btn">

                  <div class="inner"></div>

                  <button type="submit" onClick={createNewPost(e, title, content)}>Submit Post</button>

               </div>

            </form>

            </div>

      </div>

    )

}

export default CreatePost
```

I’m trying to save the data to the database, but after each input change it is saved. So if I type “hello” it saves “h”, “he”, “hel”, “hell”, “hello” and I would like it to just save hello once. Not each input change. Can someone help me fix this issue?

I'm trying to save this to moralis database, but i think the error is that the function is called multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your handler to arrow function

```
 <button type="submit" onClick={() => createNewPost(e, title, content)}>Submit Post</button>
```